Как выставить свой оффер в magiceden?
есть сайт https://magiceden.io/ , там можно покупать NFT. я хочу сделать скрипт который будет атоматически выставлять офферы для заданных коллекций. не могу понять как это сделать.
api ключ я получил.
сеть Solana
документация по api тоже есть, но не понятно все равно что нужно передавать в запросе. буду очень благодарен за информацию!
Важно! Я хочу выставить оффер на всю коллекцию, а не на конкретный NFT.

Там же всё уже есть

@DanielProtopopov очень бы хотелось получить развернутый ответ с примерами и пояснениями

А что именно не понятно в ссылке? Там есть код, целиком, в который нужно только подставить значения.

@DanielProtopopov там мы выставляем оффер на определенный нфт. а я хочу на коллекцию полностью

API Reference имеет документацию для биддинга на коллекцию через параметр collection, и соответственно, пример.
